# Get Latest Ordered Items for a Customer Across Multiple Orders

Tags: sales-order, magento2.3.3

I am trying to gather the latest 100 items a customer has purchased across all his orders. I know I can use itemCollectionFactory and go order by order, but I was wondering if there is a faster way to get directly all the items, instead of running multiple queries for each order.

With a single query, I'd also be able to make sure the same items are not shown twice in the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most effective is probably to use a SQL query with joins. E.g. like this

```
public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 1;

    $salesTable = $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order');
    $salesItemTable = $this->resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');

    $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();

    $select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
            ['sales_order' => $salesTable],
            []
        )
        ->join(
            ['sales_order_item' => $salesItemTable],
            'sales_order_item.order_id = sales_order.entity_id',
            ['sales_order_item.sku']
        )
        ->where(
            'customer_id = :customerId'
        )
        ->distinct(true)
        ->order('sales_order_item.item_id DESC')
        ->limit(100);
    $bind = ['customerId' => $customerId];

    $items = $connection->fetchAll($select, $bind);

    print_r($items);

}
```

Where $this->resource is \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection